# Проверка правильности кода, в котором реализован механизм полиморфизма

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, полиморфизм

Добрый вечер. Просьба проверить правильность моего кода, в котором реализован механизм полиморфизма, и выразить свои замечания. Ставилась задача попрактиковать в рамках одной программы вызов виртуальных методов, вызов невиртуальных методов (как базового класса, так и наследника), использовать конструкторы с параметрами.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Transport { 
protected:
    int balance, price, mileage;
public:
    Transport(int balance, int price, int mileage) {
        this->balance = balance;
        this->price = price;
        this->mileage = mileage;
    }
    virtual void get() = 0; // метод вывода на экран
    virtual void check() = 0; // метод проверки на необходимость прохождения техосмотра
    void money() {
        if (balance < price) {
            cout << "У вас недостаточно средств для покупки данного транспортного средства" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Вам по карману данное транспортное средство" << endl;
        }
    }

    virtual ~Transport() {}

};

class Train : public Transport {
private:
    int vagon, seat;
public:
    Train(int balance, int price, int mileage, int vagon):Transport(balance, price, mileage) {
        this->vagon = vagon; // количество вагонов
        seat = 50; // количество мест в одном вагоне
    }

    void get() {
        cout << "Ваш баланс: " << balance << endl;
        cout << "Стоимость поезда: " << price << endl;
        cout << "Пробег поезда: " << mileage << endl;
        cout << "Количество вагонов: " << vagon << endl;
        cout << "Количество сидячих мест в одном вагоне: " << seat << endl;
        cout << "Количество сидячих мест в поезде: " << vagon * seat << endl;
    }

    void depo() {
        if (vagon <= 25) {
            cout << "Поезд поместится в депо" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Поезд не поместится в депо" << endl;
        }
    }

    void check() {
        if (mileage > 5000000) {
                cout << "Требуется прохождение техосмотра" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Прохождение техосмотра не требуется" << endl;
        }
    }

    ~Train() {}
};

class Auto : public Transport {
protected:
    string m;
    int g, hp, t;
public:
    Auto(int balance, int price, int mileage, string m, int g, int hp):Transport(balance, price, mileage) {
        this->m = m;
        this->g = g;
        this->hp = hp;
    }

    virtual int tax() = 0; // метод вычисления налога

    void check() {
        if (mileage > 100000) {
            cout << "Требуется прохождение техосмотра" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Прохождение техосмотра не требуется" << endl;
        }
    }
    ~Auto() {}
};

class Car : public Auto {
public:
    Car(int balance, int price, int mileage, string m, int g, int hp):Auto(balance, price, mileage, m, g, hp) {}

    int tax() {
        if (hp <= 100) 
        {
            t = hp * 12;
        }
        else if (hp > 100 && hp <= 250) 
        {
            t = hp * 25;
        }
        else if (hp > 250) 
        {
            t = hp * 50;
        }
        return t;
    }

    void get() {
        cout << "Ваш баланс: " << balance << endl;
        cout << "Стоимость легкового автомобиля: " << price << endl;
        cout << "Пробег легкового автомобиля: " << mileage << endl;
        cout << "Марка и модель легкового автомобиля: " << m << endl;
        cout << "Год выпуска легкового автомобиля: " << g << endl;
        cout << "Мощность двигателя легкового автомобиля (л.с.): " << hp << endl;
        cout << "Налог за год на данный легковой автомобиль: " << t << endl;
    }
    ~Car() {}
};

class Bus : public Auto {
public:
    Bus(int balance, int price, int mileage, string m, int g, int hp):Auto(balance, price, mileage, m, g, hp) {}

    int tax() {
        if (hp <= 100)
        {
            t = hp * 19;
        }
        else if (hp > 100 && hp <= 200)
        {
            t = hp * 30;
        }

        else if (hp > 200)
        {
            t = hp * 60;
        }
        return t;
    }

    void get() {
        cout << "Ваш баланс: " << balance << endl;
        cout << "Стоимость автобуса: " << price << endl;
        cout << "Пробег автобуса: " << mileage << endl;
        cout << "Марка и модель автобуса: " << m << endl;
        cout << "Год выпуска автобуса: " << g << endl;
        cout << "Мощность двигателя автобуса (л.с.): " << hp << endl;
        cout << "Налог за год на данный автобус: " << t << endl;
    }
    ~Bus() {}
};


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int balance, price, mileage, vagon, g, hp;
    string m;

    char i = ' ';
    while (i != '4')
    {
        cout << "\nВведите 1 - чтобы выбрать поезд\n " << "\nВведите 2 - чтобы выбрать легковой автомобиль \n " << "\nВведите 3 - чтобы выбрать автобус\n " << "\nВведите 4 - для выхода \n " << endl;
        cin >> i;

        switch(i) {
        case '1': {
            cout << endl << "Конструктор класса Train" << endl;
            cout << "Введите свой баланс: ";
            cin >> balance;
            cout << "Введите стоимость поезда: ";
            cin >> price;
            cout << "Введите пробег поезда: ";
            cin >> mileage;
            cout << "Введите число вагонов поезда: ";
            cin >> vagon;
            cout << endl;

            Train train_obj(balance, price, mileage, vagon);
            Transport *transport = &train_obj;
            Train *train = &train_obj;

            transport->get();
            train->depo();
            transport->check();
            transport->money();
            //delete &train_obj;

            break;
        }

        case '2': {
            cout << endl << "Конструктор класса Car" << endl;
            cout << "Введите свой баланс: ";
            cin >> balance;
            cout << "Введите стоимость легкового автомобиля: ";
            cin >> price;
            cout << "Введите пробег легкового автомобиля: ";
            cin >> mileage;
            cout << "Введите марку и модель легкового автомобиля: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, m);
            cout << "Введите год выпуска легкового автомобиля: ";
            cin >> g;
            cout << "Введите мощность двигателя легкового автомобиля (л.с.): ";
            cin >> hp;
            cout << endl;;

            Auto *car = new Car(balance, price, mileage, m, g, hp);

            car->tax();
            car->get();
            car->check();
            car->money();
            delete car;
            break;
        }

        case '3': {
            cout << endl << "Конструктор класса Bus" << endl;
            cout << "Введите свой баланс: ";
            cin >> balance;
            cout << "Введите стоимость автобуса: ";
            cin >> price;
            cout << "Введите пробег автобуса: ";
            cin >> mileage;
            cout << "Введите марку и модель автобуса: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, m);
            cout << "Введите год выпуска автобуса: ";
            cin >> g;
            cout << "Введите мощность двигателя автобуса (л.с.): ";
            cin >> hp;
            cout << endl;;

            Auto *bus = new Bus(balance, price, mileage, m, g, hp);

            bus->tax();
            bus->get();
            bus->check();
            bus->money();
            delete bus;
            break;
        }

        case '4': {
                break;
        }

        default: {
                    cout << "Неправильный ввод" << endl;
                 }
        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Вдобавок у меня есть несколько вопросов по коду:

1) Почему программа не дает мне удалить объект train_obj?
Если добавить `delete &train_obj;` , то после того, как я введу с клавиатуры параметры этого объекта, программа вылетает с ошибкой _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) т.е. блок памяти уже удален. В то время как для удаления объектов классов Car и Bus используется `delete`, как и положено. Неужели дело в выделении памяти через `new`?

2) Я правильно понимаю, что вместо

```
Train train_obj(balance, price, mileage, vagon);
Transport *transport = &train_obj;
Train *train = &train_obj;
```

написать

```
Transport *transport = new Train(balance, price, mileage, vagon);
Train *train = new Train(balance, price, mileage, vagon);
```

будет некорректно? Так как будет создано два разных объекта

3) Почему в моем случае `getline(cin, m)` не срабатывает без `cin.ignore()` ?

4) Как предпочтительнее вызывать невиртуальный метод класса наследника - через указатель на объект (как у меня в коде) `train->depo()` или через объект `train_obj.depo()`?

```
Train train_obj(balance, price, mileage, vagon);
Transport *transport = &train_obj;
//Train *train = &train_obj;

transport->get();
train_obj.depo(); //train->depo();
transport->check();
transport->money();
```

Comment: Вы можете удалять объекты с помощью оператора delete или delete [] только при условии, что они были созданы с использованием оператора new. Объект train_obj не был создан с помощью оператора new, а является локальной переменной. О его удалении позаботится компилятор, когда объект выйдет за пределы своей области объявления.

Comment: т.е. train_obj это статическая переменная?

Comment: Это не статическая переменная, а переменная с автоматической памятью, которая будет освобождена автоматически. Компилятор сам подставит необходимый код для ее удаления.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему программа не дает мне удалить объект train_obj?

Потому что его деструктор и так вызывается по окончании срока жизни объекта `train_obj`. Явно вызывать деструктор нужно было бы, если бы он создавался динамически:

```
Train *train = new Train(balance, price, mileage, vagon);
/* ... */
delete train;
```

Учитывая следующий вопрос - не очень понятно зачем вам дополнительный указатель типа `Transport`, но если хочется, то:

```
Train *train = new Train(balance, price, mileage, vagon);
Transport *transport = train;
```

Вопрос 4: без разницы.

Comment: Указатель типа Transport необходим для вызова переопределенных виртуальных методов get() и check()

Comment: Всё равно непонятно чего вы этим хотите добиться. Вызова методов базового класса?

Comment: Я хотел добиться осуществления полиморфизма - имея указатель на Transport можно вызвать реализацию виртуальной функции любого производного класса, если присвоить этому указателю адрес объекта производного класса.